# Assembly Code - Number Counter

Tags: assembly, counter, whitespace, lc3

I am a beginner to assembly code and I was wondering how to create a counter the counts how many numbers the user inputs. The program prompts the user to input some numbers, separated by a space bar/white space. Once ENTER is pressed, the program stops scanning for any more input. 
I was wondering how I could exclude the space bar inputs and only count the numbers?

This is my code so far:

```
.orig x3000

lea r0 stringA
puts

and r3 r3 0

lea r2 input
begin getc
str r0 r2 0
add r2 r2 1
out

add r1 r0 -10
brz outside

add r3 r3 #1

br begin
outside 

lea r0 stringB
puts
ld r0 characterZero
add r0 r0 r3
out

halt

stringA .stringz "Numbers: "
stringB .stringz "Amount of Numbers: "
characterZero .fill x30
input .blkw 9

.end
```

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You already seem to have a check for Linefeed (ASCII 10), so you could just add another comparison for space (ASCII 32) and only increment `r2` for non-space characters.

Comment: How would I check for the SPACE character? Would it be the same as checking for the ENTER character? I tried that but an error would say "Cannot be represented as a signed number in 5 bits"

Comment: A space character, as Michael already said, is ASCII character 32. You compare a single byte against the value 32. If it matches, it's a space. If it doesn't match, it's not a space.

Comment: Figured it out, took a while but i did it :D Thanks guys